# How to detect android double tap?

Tags: android, double-click, tap

How to detect the double tap in android? I implement OnDoubleTapListener and wrote this:

```
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getAction() == 1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But it is not working. What is the wrong with this?

Comment: Try removing the if block and just make a Toast when you receive the event. That will let us know if the listener is properly attached.

Comment: I removed if block and test again. Still I couldn't see the Toast message for double tap.

Comment: @Emmanuel :  Yah thanks, I saw the given post but I did not understand the given code as the answer. He created new class for that. What I need is to do it inside my activity. I don't have much experience in android and I'm sorry if this is like stupid.

Answer (score 6):

```
public class GestureDoubleTap extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        //some logic
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

```
GestureDoubleTap gestureDoubleTap = new GestureDoubleTap();
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this/* context */, gestureDoubleTap);

view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, But is there any way to do this inside Activity without creating separate class as GestureDoubleTap ?

Comment: Anonymous class instead separate class as GestureDoubleTap,otherwise,i'm sorry i have no idea.

Comment: Have another question here how to identify particular icon? Using MotionEvent we can get X and Y coordinates but using that how can I get exact icon which has double tap?

Comment: first,one icon,one view.second if one view has several icon.you must know the the size of each icon.either,the left point.so, in onDoubleTap(),you just do some logic to calculate x and y in which icon.