# How to make sure that the onscreen keyboard comes out only when the user double tap on edittext?

Tags: android, xml

I want to make an editable layout in android where the edit option and keyboard opens up only when the user does a double tap on the box, so that the screen remains readable and keyboard comes up only when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to give you a basic idea:

1) Create your own `GestureDetector` as described in many answers, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941959/how-to-detect-android-double-tap)

2) Set an `OnTouchListener` for your `View` and check for the `onTouchEvent()` method result. Return **true** from `onTouch()` to prevent the system from showing the keyboard on `EditText` single tap.

3) Use the [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) to show/hide the soft keyboard as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why a normal single tap won't suffice, but you might want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7839242/2750877) answer to a similar question.